# Can no longer access WSL2 files from Windows explorer or launch Windows programs from WSL2

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been running WSL2 on Windows 10 for several months now and just recently lost these abilities. I can still open a WSL2 terminal and interact with my Ubuntu installation there.

**Accessing WSL2 files from explorer**

I could previously go to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu` and see all my WSL2 files. I can still see the Ubuntu folder at `\\wsl$`, but when I try to open it I get a loading bar and nothing happens (even after waiting for a long time):
[image: Cannot open Ubuntu folder]

Also in Powershell:
[image]

**Opening Windows program from WSL2**

Previously I could open Windows programs like explorer and VSCode from a WSL2 terminal with `explorer.exe` and `code` respectively. Now when I try this the terminal just hangs and nothing opens.

Note that I can still navigate to `/mnt/` and see all my Windows files from the WSL2 terminal.

---

I'm running Windows 10 Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.1379) and Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: After providing suggestions below, I noticed that this was on Stack Overflow.  Since it's not directly a *programming* question, it really should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I have an *answer* for you, but some general troubleshooting steps to try:

- Exit your instances and try a `wsl --shutdown`.
- If that works, try turning off Windows Fast Startup.  Also avoid hibernation.  These are known to interfere with some WSL network functionality.
- Try adding the following section to your `/etc/wsl.conf`:

  ```
  [interop]
  enabled = true
  ```

  This should be the default, but it wouldn't be the first time we've seen WSL not following the defaults for some reason.
- Make sure your Windows temp directory is not compressed
- Make sure your distribution folder under `%userprofile%/Local/AppData/Packages` is not compressed, especially the `LocalState` subdirectory where the `ext4.vhdx` lives.
- If enabled, try turning off Windows Ransomware Protection

Comment: In my personal experience, disabling Windows Fast Startup fixes the issue straight away

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (although on Windows 11). It was very annoying. I noticed that after a restart it was ok, but after a few minutes and almost always after running VSCode, it was breaking again. Here's what worked for me:

- exporting my distro (`wsl --export <Distro> <FileName>`)
- unregistering it from WSL (`wsl --unregister <Distro>`)
- uninstalling all WSL-related stuff, like the optional Windows feature, the WSL app from the store (I had them both). I also removed  WSLg but I'm not sure if that was necessary
- restarting
- installing again the app from the store ([no need to turn on the optional Windows feature anymore in case you are on build 22000 or higher](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-preview-of-wsl-in-the-microsoft-store-is-now-available/))
- finally just reimporting the distro (`wsl --import <Distro> <InstallLocation> <FileName>`)

After going through the above steps the issue was resolved and now my WSL2 works like a charm.